# How do you build a C# project on Atlassian OnDemand?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, bamboo

I've been building my C# project from the MS Visual Studio IDE, and by invoking msbuild from Jenkins on Windows. Now I want to build the C# project on Atlassian OnDemand.

However, msbuild is not listed as a builder option in OnDemand and I can't find any documentation on how to build a C# project on OnDemand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

Atlassian OnDemand Bamboo features a Windows stock image as of mid July 2012, see Azwandi Mohd Aris' [comment](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/558/how-do-i-run-net-builds-on-jira-studio/78033):

> Just an update that Bamboo OnDemand now ships with a Windows-based AMI - see release notes at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/July+2012#July2012-Bambooupgrade

This image meanwhile also supports MSBuild as per James Dumay's [answer](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/30624/how-can-i-run-bamboo-ondemand-with-msbuild/103775) from early November 2012.

---

### Initial Answer

The configuration of builders is one of the [Restricted Functions in Atlassian OnDemand for Bamboo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Restricted+Functions+in+Atlassian+OnDemand#RestrictedFunctionsinAtlassianOnDemand-Bamboo):

> Bamboo OnDemand only runs builds using elastic agents. Hence,
>   capabilities can only be configured by [using a custom image](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=253231639).

So in principle you would need to either use one of the default [Stock images](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO40/Stock+images) provided by Atlassian or [Create a custom elastic image](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO40/Creating+a+custom+elastic+image) of our own. While Atlassian provides a [Windows stock image](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO40/Stock+images#Stockimages-Windowsstockimage) as of Bamboo 3.4, the version of Bamboo for OnDemand is most annoyingly still stuck at 3.0 (see [Atlassian OnDemand Application Versions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Atlassian+OnDemand+Application+Versions)), with the long overdue update including DVCS support recently postponed again (see [Lingbo Lu's comment](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Atlassian+OnDemand+Application+Versions?focusedCommentId=283640209#comment-283640209): *We are hoping that we can deliver it in July/August timeframe*)

So for the time being I'm afraid you'll need to apply the Bamboo 3.0 version of [Creating a Custom Elastic Image](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO030/Creating+a+Custom+Elastic+Image) and create an appropriate custom image for the task at hand yourself.

#### Update

There are a couple of related threads on [Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/) as well:

James Dumay's answer to [How do I run .NET builds on JIRA Studio](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/558/how-do-i-run-net-builds-on-jira-studio/604) summarizes the state of affairs and recommends Grace Mollison's instructions for [Setting up a windows AMI for use with Elastic Bamboo](http://devopscloud.net/2011/03/25/setting-up-a-windows-ami-for-use-with-elastic-bamboo/) in turn. However, RodH's comment regarding [How can I run Bamboo OnDemand with MSBuild?](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/30624/how-can-i-run-bamboo-ondemand-with-msbuild/30756) indicates unspecified issues with this approach/solution.

So be prepared for a rough ride eventually.